# Get the HTML code from a website after entering Form Data using POST method

Tags: http, post, python-requests, get

I need to extract the HTML code sent back to me when I am in a browser in a particular website. The page I need to parse only appears when I enter data in a form using **POST** method.
I am designing a piece of code in a language (let's say python) using requests or any other HTTP Request module in other languages. The problem is that the responses of a POST does not contain the HTML code returned by the server.
Is there any way for me to tackle this? Let's say the website I am scraping from doesn't have an API and the only way for me to check data is to submit form data and then the page loads into the required one.

Comment: the post request should return a response with a body... if you say that url doesn't return the response body you are expecting it's impossible to give you any meaningful answer.

Comment: Uh thanks for opening my eyes. Simply the framework I was using doesn't display the HTML body. I just needed to specify to the framework.